# How can I aggregate geocoded data by a shapefile polygon for visualisation using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, r-sp

I have a geocoded dataset that I am trying to aggregate into polygons so that I can to plot the results as a series of choropleth maps at different levels (e.g. suburb, local government area etc.).

To do so, I am following an approach - [shown here](http://ryanruthart.com/using-r-to-perform-a-spatial-join-and-aggregate-data/) - which uses the `over` function in the `sp` package to join the data with a spatial object and find which polygon my co-ordinates (from a separate file) fall in. I've then fortified the spatial object to plot using `ggplot2`.

By and large, I seem to have got most of the process working okay, however as you can see from the resulting chart. I’m clearly not doing something correct when I'm matching the coordinates to the polygons. The polygons (denoting suburbs) should be whole shapes. I can't work out which bit of my workflow is causing this mess. 
[image: Dodgy polygons]
Can anyone advise where I might be going wrong here? Is there a better way to solve the point-in-polygon problem than using `over`?

The shapefile can be downloaded from the Australian Bureau of Statistics website [here](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1270.0.55.003July%202011?OpenDocument) (File: "State Suburbs ASGS Non ABS Structures Ed 2011 Digital Boundaries in ESRI Shapefile Format"). I have saved some geocoded example data in a google sheet which can be accessed by running the code below.

My initial attempt is in the code below:

```
## LOAD REQUIRED PACKAGES

library(googlesheets)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)

## READ DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEETS FILE

googleDocKey <- "1IyXSC0dtOCh1xGFiBG38nKzK2nO8wKUECRCEhvtZVS0"
geoCodedData <- googleDocKey %>% gs_key()
geoData <- geoCodedData %>% gs_read(ws = "geoData", range = cell_limits()) 
suburbList <- geoCodedData %>% gs_read(ws = "suburbList", range = cell_limits())

## SET COORDINATES FROM GEOCODED DATA

geoData <- as.data.frame(geoData)
coordinates(geoData) <- c("Longitude","Latitude")

## LOAD AUSTRALIA SHAPEFILE AND SUBSET FOR NSW 
## YOU WILL NEED TO DOWNLOAD THIS FILE FROM THE ABS MANUALLY (LINK ABOVE)

ausSuburbs <- readOGR(dsn ="02 - Shapefiles", layer="SSC_2011_AUST")
suburbList$SSC_CODE_2011 <- as.numeric(suburbList$SSC_CODE_2011)
nswSuburbList <- suburbList %>%
        filter(SSC_CODE_2011 < 20000) %>%
        filter(SSC_CODE_2011 > 9999) %>%
        select(SSC_CODE_2011)
nswSuburbs <- ausSuburbs[ausSuburbs$SSC_CODE %in% nswSuburbList$SSC_CODE_2011, ]   
nswSuburbs <- nswSuburbs[!nswSuburbs$SSC_CODE %in% 11408,] # exclude Lord Howe Island

## TELL R THAT THE COORDINATES IN THE SHAPEFILE MATCH THOSE IN THE SPATIAL POINTS DATA FRAME

proj4string(geoData) <- proj4string(nswSuburbs)

## ASSIGN UNIQUE IDENTIFIER TO EACH SPATIAL OBJECT

nswSuburbs@data$id <- rownames(nswSuburbs@data)

nswSuburbs@data <- mutate(nswSuburbs@data, id_poly = as.numeric(rownames(nswSuburbs@data)))

geoData@data <- mutate(geoData@data, id_shape = as.numeric(rownames(geoData@data)))

## GET THE SUBURB THAT THE POINT IS LOCATED IN

gpsSuburb <- over(geoData, nswSuburbs)

## ADD 'id_shape' TO THE DATA FRAME

gpsSuburbID <- mutate(gpsSuburb, id_shape = as.numeric(rownames(gpsSuburb)))

## AGGREGATE DROP BEAR DATA BY SUBURB

gpsSuburbJoin <- left_join(geoData@data, gpsSuburbID, by = c("id_shape" = "id_shape"))
gpsSuburbData <- gpsSuburbJoin %>%
        group_by(SSC_CODE) %>%
        summarise(DropBearSightings = sum(DropBearSightings))
gpsSuburbData <- as.data.frame(gpsSuburbData)

## CONVERT SHAPEFILE TO DATA FRAME TO ALLOW DATA TO BE JOINED TO IT

nswPoints <- fortify(nswSuburbs, region="id")
nswData <- merge(nswPoints, nswSuburbs, by="id", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
nswData$id <- as.numeric(nswData$id)

nswSuburbMapData <- merge(nswData, gpsSuburbData, by="SSC_CODE", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
nswSuburbMapData <- nswSuburbMapData[order(nswSuburbMapData$id,     nswSuburbMapData$id),]

## SET THEME FOR GGPLOT

theme_clean <- function(base_size = 12) {
        require(grid)
        theme_grey(base_size) %+replace%
                    theme(
                                axis.title = element_blank(),
                                axis.text = element_blank(),
                                panel.background = element_blank(),
                                panel.grid = element_blank(),
                                axis.ticks.length = unit(0,"cm"), 
                                axis.ticks.margin = unit(0,"cm"),
                                panel.margin = unit(0,"lines"),
                                plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "lines"),
                                complete = TRUE
                    )}

## PLOT TEST MAP USING GGPLOT

dropBearMap <- ggplot(nswSuburbMapData) +
        aes(long, lat, group=group, fill=DropBearSightings) +
        geom_polygon() +
        coord_map(projection = "mercator", xlim = c(140.0, 154.0), ylim = c(-38.0, -27.0)) +
theme_clean()
dropBearMap
#ggsave("dropBearMap.png", type = "cairo-png")
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice for how to solve this issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright my first answer was wayyyy off...I don't have much experience with dplyr and got overly nervous when the data slot was being edited. The problem is much simpler. The merge function messes up the order of the fortified shape file which needs to be restored prior to plotting so this:

`nswSuburbMapData <- nswSuburbMapData[order(nswSuburbMapData$id,     nswSuburbMapData$id),]`

needs to become this:

`nswSuburbMapData <- nswSuburbMapData[order(nswSuburbMapData$order),]`

Which produces this when plotted:

[image]

You'll probably need to make some additional changes for the map to be more useful but this should be the data represented correctly.

Comment: Thanks very much @Adam Mccurdy - its works a charm. Very much appreciated.